# eshell: activate Python virtual environment from command prompt

Tags: python, eshell

I am aware of additional Lisp libraries that are able to activate a Python virtual environment without typing the following from an `eshell` command prompt:  `source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`.  However, I would like to understand what the limitation is that prevents `eshell` from being able to execute that command.  [Once I get beyond that initial hurdle, I can craft my own function to modify the `process-environment`, etc.]

**ESHELL**:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

/ $ (setq debug-on-error t)
t
/ $ (setenv "LANG" "UTF-8")
UTF-8
/ $ /path/to/bin/virtualenv-3.8 -v /path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_api
find interpreter for spec PythonSpec(path=/path/to/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8)
proposed PythonInfo(spec=CPython3.8.6.final.0-64, exe=/path/to/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8, platform=darwin, version='3.8.6 (default, Dec 18 2021, 14:27:40) \n[Clang 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]', encoding_fs_io=utf-8-utf-8)
create virtual environment via CPython3Posix(dest=/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_api, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
add seed packages via FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
add activators for Bash, CShell, Fish, PowerShell, Python, Xonsh
created virtual environment CPython3.8.6.final.0-64 in 326ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_api, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.1, setuptools==51.0.0, wheel==0.36.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
/ $ source /path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_api/bin/activate
/ $ # This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly


if [ "${BASH_SOURCE-}" = "$0" ]; then
    echo "You must source this script: \$ source $0" >&2
    exit 33
fi

deactivate () {
    unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1

    # reset old environment variables
    # ! [ -z ${VAR+_} ] returns true if VAR is declared at all
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:+_}" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2>/dev/null
    fi

    if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1+_}" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV='/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_api'
if ([ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ] || [ "$OSTYPE" = "msys" ]) && $(command -v cygpath &> /dev/null) ; then
    VIRTUAL_ENV=$(cygpath -u "$VIRTUAL_ENV")
fi
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
if ! [ -z "${PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1-}"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="${PS1-}"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1-}"
    fi
    export PS1
fi

# Make sure to unalias pydoc if it's already there
alias pydoc 2>/dev/null >/dev/null && unalias pydoc || true

pydoc () {
    python -m pydoc "$@"
}

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

**DEBUGGER**:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Missing redirection target")
  signal(error ("Missing redirection target"))
  error("Missing redirection target")
  eshell-strip-redirections(("unset" "-f" "pydoc" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite)))
  run-hook-with-args(eshell-strip-redirections ("unset" "-f" "pydoc" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite)))
  eshell-parse-pipeline(("unset" "-f" "pydoc" (eshell-set-output-handle 1 'overwrite) "/dev/null" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite)))
  #f(compiled-function (cmd) #<bytecode 0x41814335>)(("unset" "-f" "pydoc" (eshell-set-output-handle 1 'overwrite) "/dev/null" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite)))
  mapcar(#f(compiled-function (cmd) #<bytecode 0x41814335>) (nil ("unset" "-f" "pydoc" (eshell-set-output-handle 1 'overwrite) "/dev/null" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite)) nil nil nil ("if" "!" "[" "-z" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) (eshell-extended-glob "]")) ("then") ((eshell-convert (concat "PATH=" (eshell-to-flat-string (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-convert ...)))))) ("export" "PATH") ("unset" "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH") ("fi") ("if" "!" "[" "-z" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) (eshell-extended-glob "]")) ("then") ((eshell-convert (concat "PYTHONHOME=" (eshell-to-flat-string (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-convert ...)))))) ("export" "PYTHONHOME") ("unset" "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME") ("fi") nil nil nil nil ("if" "[" "-n" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) (eshell-extended-glob "]") (eshell-operator "||") "[" "-n" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) (eshell-extended-glob "]")) ("then") ("hash" "-r" (eshell-set-output-handle 2 'overwrite) "/dev/null") ("fi") nil ("if" "!" "[" "-z" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) (eshell-extended-glob "]")) ("then") ((eshell-convert (concat "PS1=" (eshell-to-flat-string (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-convert ...)))))) ("export" "PS1") ("unset" "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1") ("fi") nil ("unset" "VIRTUAL_ENV") ("if" "[" "!" (eshell-escape-arg (eshell-escape-arg (let ((indices ...)) (eshell-convert (eshell-command-to-value ...))))) "=" (eshell-escape-arg "nondestructive") (eshell-extended-glob "]")) ("then") nil ("unset" "-f" "deactivate") ("fi")))
  eshell-parse-command((1877 . 2900))
  eshell-parse-subcommand-argument()
  run-hook-with-args-until-success(eshell-parse-subcommand-argument)
  eshell-parse-argument()
  eshell-parse-arguments(1656 4045)
  eshell-parse-command((1656 . 4045))
  eshell-source-file("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap..." nil t)
  eshell/source("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")
  apply(eshell/source "/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")
  eshell-exec-lisp(eshell-print eshell-error eshell/source ("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...") nil)
  eshell-lisp-command(eshell/source ("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap..."))
  eshell-plain-command("source" ("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap..."))
  eshell-named-command("source" ("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap..."))
  eval((eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")))
  eshell-do-eval((eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")) nil)
  eshell-do-eval((prog1 (eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) nil)
  (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '(prog1 (eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) nil) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  eval((condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '(prog1 (eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) nil) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1))))
  eshell-do-eval((condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '(prog1 (eshell-named-command '"source" '("/path/to/.0.virtualenvs/tda_ap...")) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) nil) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1))) nil)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fda9>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fda9>))
  (let ((eshell-this-command-hook '(ignore))) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fda9>)))
  eval((let ((eshell-this-command-hook '(ignore))) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fda9>))))
  eshell-do-eval((let ((eshell-this-command-hook '(ignore))) (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '(prog1 (eshell-named-command '"source" '...) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook)) nil) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))) nil)
  eshell-do-eval((progn (let ((eshell-this-command-hook '(ignore))) (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '(prog1 (eshell-named-command ... ...) (mapc ... eshell-this-command-hook)) nil) ((debug error) (mapc #'funcall eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1))))) nil)
  (catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let ((eshell-this-command-hook '...)) (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval '... nil) ((debug error) (mapc ... eshell-this-command-hook) (eshell-errorn ...) (eshell-close-handles 1))))) nil))
  eval((catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let ((eshell-this-command-hook ...)) (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval ... nil) (... ... ... ...)))) nil)))
  eshell-do-eval((catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let ((eshell-this-command-hook ...)) (condition-case err (eshell-do-eval ... nil) (... ... ... ...)))) nil)) nil)
  eshell-do-eval((progn 'nil (catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let (...) (condition-case err ... ...))) nil)) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook)) nil)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fd89>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fd89>))
  (let ((eshell-current-subjob-p 'nil) (eshell-current-handles '[nil (t . 1) (t . 1)])) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fd89>)))
  eval((let ((eshell-current-subjob-p 'nil) (eshell-current-handles '[nil (t . 1) (t . 1)])) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4142fd89>))))
  eshell-do-eval((let ((eshell-current-handles '[nil (t . 1) (t . 1)]) eshell-current-subjob-p) (progn 'nil (catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let ... ...)) nil)) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook))))
  eshell-resume-eval()
  eshell-eval-command((let ((eshell-current-handles '[nil (t . 1) (t . 1)]) eshell-current-subjob-p) (progn 'nil (catch 'top-level (eshell-do-eval '(progn (let ... ...)) nil)) (run-hooks 'eshell-post-command-hook))) "source /path/to/.0.virtualenvs...")
  eshell-send-input(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eshell-send-input nil)
  call-interactively(eshell-send-input nil nil)
  command-execute(eshell-send-input)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `source` command reads in a file and executes it within the current environment. When you run `source foo` in a Bash shell, it expects the file called foo to have bash syntax in it. When you run `source foo` in Eshell, it expects the file to have eshell syntax in it. These syntaxes are not the same!

You tried to execute a Bash script inside Eshell, which just isn’t going to work. Since Bash is so popular, virtualenv assumes that you aren’t going to use something else.